# Class Diagram for Magento

Tags: php, javascript, magento, uml

Does any one have a class diagram for magento?

I'm only seeing an ERD in the internet. and I believe that Class Diagram is different from ERD.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento is mostly based on the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/), so you can probably derive a lot of the structure from the way the framework does it. I don't think that anybody made the effort of creating a UML diagram for the whole application. Last requests for that are now three years old and apparently never went anywhere.